# Infinite scroll for sql items

Tags: sql, scroll

I'm trying to a segment of code which is behaving strange.

I am using the Paul Irish infinite scroll with the JQuery masonry plugin to display content.

The content is pulled by sql and has a set number, currently 20.

This means the page will load the first 20 rows of content from the database, then will load the next 20 upon scrolling down.

I have this functionality on a few pages and it works fine except for one page.

On this page instead of loading the most recent 20 posts, it loads every post in that particular field. Some have over 5000 posts so it literally crashes the page. A major problem as you can imagine.

I have been trying to adapt the code to look for anomalies and have narrowed it down (I think) to one particular segment.

This is the code used on a page that works:

```
function index() {
    $userID = false;
    $order = false;
    $limit = $this->config->item('pin_load_limit');
    $page = $this->uri->segment(3, 1);

    $nextOffset = ($page -1) * $limit;
    $nextPage = $page +1;
    $sql = "SELECT *
                FROM
                    pins";

    if ($userID)
        $sql .= " WHERE
                    user_id= $userID ";

    if ($order) {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY
                    ' $order'";
    } else {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY time DESC";
    }
    $sql .= " LIMIT $nextOffset,$limit";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $row = $query->result();
    }
```

This is the code on the page that doesn't work:

```
    function getEachBoardPins($id,$limit=false)
{
    $sql    = "SELECT 
                    *
                FROM
                    pins
                WHERE
                    board_id = $id
                ORDER BY time DESC";
    if($limit)
        $sql .=" LIMIT 0 ,$limit" ;
    $query  = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result();
}
```

I know it is to do with the pin load limit but I have tried adding the code to the latter without success.

Perhaps somebody on here who knows more about it can provide some better insight?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that it is VERY LIKELY that when you call the "getEachBoardPins" function, you aren't setting the second parameter, hence, it is defaulting to false, hence, the limit SQL isn't being appended, so the select statement will run the whole statement.

Comment: I see what you mean but I also tried putting the $limit variable in the statement without the 'if' clause and it still pulls every row, not the last 20.

Comment: I misunderstood.
When I add the second parameter, defined as:
    
        $limit = $this->config->item('pin_load_limit');

The page only loads 20. Which is the 'pin_load_limit', but doesn't scroll to anymore.